# Ubuntu 12.04(32bit) Dropbox keep showing "Connecting"

Tags: 12.04, dropbox

I have some questions about executing Dropbox on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ( 32bit ).

After I followed this instruction and tried to install Dropbox,

32-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

when I typed this instruction to continue,

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

the cursor is left at the same position,
and nothing popped out, so I can't continue...

The Dropbox icon on the right-up-side bar remains grey...

and when I type this in the terminal

```
dropbox status
```

it keeps showing "Connecting...", and nothing happens.

I tried to reinstall (remove and install again, logout and login), it just can't work.

Can someone please help me on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I set Dropbox to sync to an automounted partition. When I changed it to a local system partition and restarted the service it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that installation. 
Then go to your home folder and delete .dropbox and .dropbox-dist folders.

Install it again from here:
https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_1.6.0_i386.deb